# Plugin error while building ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework

during build ionic app,  this error is shown:

> Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova). Your plugins
>          may be out of date.
>       TypeError: env.runcmd is not a function

Comment: Update all packages to latest, delete your node_modules and run npm install.
Make sure all your files and folders are lower case and the references to them in the .ts import statements are also lower case.

Answer (score 16):

This error message indicates that the Ionic CLI version is incompatible with other CLI plugins (see https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12561).

Please run the following commands in your project directory (where you package.json is):

```
npm i -g ionic@latest
npm i --save-dev --save-exact ionic@latest
```

This will install the latest Ionic CLI version (currently 3.7.0) globally and locally. After that the error should no longer occur.

Comment: with version 3.8.1 of ionic, you need to delete @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova from package.json

Answer (score 0):

If you have ionic cli version lower than `3.6.0` try to update it. It resolved the issue for me.