# ionic building TypeError: env.runcmd is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

During build of an ionic App, this error is shown:
[image]

anyone can help me ?

Comment: Did you check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/45475362/4587148 ?

Comment: pwagner's answer in the thread posted by Sajan did the trick! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says:

> Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin
>   (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova). Your plugins may be out of
>          date.

Did you try to install latest cordova plug-in :

```
$> npm install @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova@latest
```

Also update the dependencies....

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just change version package.json of this two plugins under `devDependencies` section. (In your case version number may differ)

```
 "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova" : "1.4.1",
 "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular" : "1.3.2"
```

after this change in `package.json` run below command:

```
npm update
```

Now try to build, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Things to try:

1. run "cordova platform add ios" and "cordova platform add android"
2. run npm install --save --save-exact ionic@3.6.0 and then upgrade it to newest version
3. if it still does not work then just do downgrade without upgrade and wait until stable version will be released

Answer (score 1):

The main problem for me was the @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova , so I downgraded it to v1.4.1 ( Don't know if any of the later versions are working fine.)

Command:
npm install --save-dev @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova@1.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I my case what I did was went to the project folder and ran the following command to Get it working

```
cd platforms/ios/cordova && npm install ios-sim@latest
```