# Could not make a product build

Tags: angular, ionic2

HI i am trying to make a build to launch my app in play store so i tried to make a product build

in my main.ts file i added this line

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';


enableProdMode();
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

And i am getting this error
[image]

Could someone help please

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573923/ionic-building-typeerror-env-runcmd-is-not-a-function

Comment: no changes still i get the same problem  @suraj

Comment: Try to update ionic to latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not how you do a production build with ionic. Remove the lines you added and use `ionic cordova build <platform> --prod` to trigger an optimized build.

To upload your application to Google-Play you need to do a release build:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

And you need to sign the resulting .apk with your .keystore:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

As a final step you need to zipalign your .apk:

```
zipalign -v 4 my-release-unsigned.apk MyFinalSignedAndZipaligned.apk
```

[Here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/) you can find the ionic documentation on how to deploy your application.

Comment: it worked, could you tell me how to generate signed apk @david