# when making .apk file generate error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-v1

When i run (  ionic cordova build android --release   ) to make .apk file . the error occur ( TypeError: env.runcmd is not a function). I try following step to resolve like.
1.npm install @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova@latest
it not solve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [During building ionic app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45475362/during-building-ionic-app)

Comment: CLI version problem
run this code
`npm i -g ionic@latest`

then

`npm i --save-dev --save-exact ionic@latest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be issues with your plugins out of date or any bugs with latest upgrades.

Try :

> ```
>   Remove your node_modules folder 
>   npm install --save --save-exact ionic@3.6.0 
>   npm install
> ```

Freshly install all the node modules.